# Why is ngFor object list ignoring certain values?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, ngfor

I have a MEAN app I'm working on. In the backend we have the mongoDB collections users, resumes, experiences. These build off each other so users have resumes, resumes have experiences. There is also an API that does various tasks like add resume, add experience, get all experiences, etc.

In the front end, I'm using angular and node (along with bootstrap) to display the info and add GUI functionality. So I have this code in the experience model:

```
class ExperienceModel {
    _id!: string;
    _userId!: string;
    _resumeId!: string;
    employer!: string;
    monthStart!: string;
    yearStart!: string;
    monthEnd!: string;
    yearEnd!: string;
    title!: string;
    description!: string;
}

export default ExperienceModel;
```

and in the main component screen ts file I declare `experiences: ExperienceModel[] = [];` and in ngOnInit this block of code:

```
if (this.userId && this.resumeId) {
          this.experienceService.getExperiences(this.userId, this.resumeId).subscribe(
            (allExperiences: ExperienceModel[]) => { this.experiences = allExperiences }
          );
        }
```

Finally in the html file for the main component screen, I have this *ngFor loop populating a list:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" 
   *ngFor="let experience of experiences"
   class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
       {{ experience }}
   <span (click)="deleteExperience(experience)" class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">x</span>
</a>
```

NOW, the problem is, the list is displaying two things, each of which look like [Object object] though there are three experience files in the collection. In addition to that, if I type something like {{ experience._id }} or _userId or _resumeId it works, and if I type something like {{ experience.title }} or employer or description it's just showing two empty boxes. I have tested the API call with insomnia and there are three files coming back in the response. Let me know if there's anything else you need to know, appreciate the help.

EDIT 1:
Here is the JSON from the API retrieved in Insomnia:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61841026178ac959d07f80df",
    "_userId": "61705675ab8731ad3a794751",
    "_resumeId": "617057308799dd688b117ce3",
    "employer": "Some company",
    "monthStart": "03",
    "yearStart": "2021",
    "monthEnd": "06",
    "yearEnd": "2021",
    "title": "Director of Awesome",
    "description": "Coolest guy on staff, had to make sure everyone else was cool too",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "6184119e178ac959d07f810f",
    "_userId": "61705675ab8731ad3a794751",
    "_resumeId": "617057308799dd688b117ce3",
    "employer": "Some other company",
    "monthStart": "05",
    "yearStart": "2020",
    "monthEnd": "09",
    "yearEnd": "2020",
    "title": "Director of Cool",
    "description": "Phatest b-boi on staff, had to make sure everyone was kicking it with funky rythms",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "618411cd178ac959d07f8112",
    "_userId": "61705675ab8731ad3a794751",
    "_resumeId": "617057308799dd688b117ce3",
    "employer": "test",
    "monthStart": "05",
    "yearStart": "2020",
    "monthEnd": "09",
    "yearEnd": "2020",
    "title": "Director of Cool",
    "description": "Phatest b-boi on staff, had to make sure everyone was kicking it with funky rythms",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

and here's what I'm seeing through the API link in my browser:

```
[{"_id":"61718f3e0624ec1944bde7fa","_userId":"61705675ab8731ad3a794751","_resumeId":"6170b39b0624ec1944bde78b","experience":{"monthStart":"10","yearStart":"2020","monthEnd":"03","yearEnd":"2021","title":"Director of Cool","description":"Coolest guy on staff, had to make sure everyone else was cool too"},"__v":0},{"_id":"61718f510624ec1944bde7fc","_userId":"61705675ab8731ad3a794751","_resumeId":"6170b39b0624ec1944bde78b","experience":{"monthStart":"03","yearStart":"2021","monthEnd":"06","yearEnd":"2021","title":"Director of Awesome","description":"Coolest guy on staff, had to make sure everyone else was cool too"},"__v":0}]
```

Comment: Can you paste here the JSON you're receiving from your endpoint?

Comment: Is there a way I can see that in the javascript console or with some developer tool? I've been having a hard time debugging because no matter where I put a break point the app just compiles and serves and never breaks. or do you mean from the RestAPI via insomnia?

Comment: You said you can see the response and it's correct. I would like to see it as well :)

Comment: OK I edited question. I am seeing a discrepancy here though... for some reason the API call is showing the data how it should exist now and the javascript call is getting it like it used to be with an "experience": Object key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the JSON you receive.

Based on that, you get *two* objects which is correct.

When you print `{{ experience }}` that is an object javascript will render as `[Object object]`. You can see all the content with the json pipe `{{ experience | json }}`

And the last point, why some fields are not shown... again it is answered on the JSON you receive: the structure is different from what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the json you receive from API, there is an extra experience object in it. See the image.

You can use like this in template

```
 <a style="cursor: pointer" 
   *ngFor="let experience of experiences"
   class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
       {{ experience.experience.title }}
   <span (click)="deleteExperience(experience)" class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">x</span>
</a>
```